# Xml documentation <code> tag shows C# for VB.NET code

Tags: vb.net, sandcastle, xml-documentation

I am trying to use the <code> tag inside the <example> tag to show a sample code in xml documentation. However, when I build the Sandcastle project, I see that it is shown as C#. There is no language attribute in <code> tag. And I could not find a setting in Sandcastle's project properties. Am I missing something?

BTW, I am using HtmlHelp1 format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, if you move beyond Sandcastle to [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) (SHFB),
 you will get *both* an easier to use interface to Sandcastle *and* additional features for your documentation set, including just what you want: a language attribute (`language`) for the `<code>` element.

Note that SHFB generates a language selector menu but that only lets you 
show or hide a particular set of languages (C#, VB.NET, C++, J#, JScript.NET, XAML, and JavaScript). It supports colorizing, though, of a larger set (C#, VB.NET, JScript.NET, C++, J#, C, JavaScript, VBScript, XAML, XML, HTML, SQL script, PowerShell script, and Python). (From the [Code Block Component](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/7f03ba39-09f8-4320-bdbd-ed31a3bd885f.htm) section of the SHFB documentation.)

I have written extensively on this point, as well as many other tips and pitfalls of Sandcastle and SHFB, in my article [Taming Sandcastle: A .NET Programmer's Guide to Documenting Your Code](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/taming-sandcastle-a-.net-programmers-guide-to-documenting-your-code/) published on Simple-Talk.com. Besides the main article, I also put together a [wallchart/quick reference](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/entrypage/code-profiling-made-easy-sandcastlechart?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=email-reflector&utm_content=sandcastlechart&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler) that gives you everything you need to know to use Sandcastle/SHFB on one page--the link also appears at the end of the article.

You can find more details about the `<code>` element in the [Displaying Sample Code](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/taming-sandcastle-a-.net-programmers-guide-to-documenting-your-code/#twentyfirst) section of my article, as well as from the official SHFB documentation at [Importing and Colorizing Code from Source Files](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/1863a4d7-61b6-4dde-862d-a358d0cfbd54.htm).

Comment: I was already using SHFB but could not find any code language sample. The last link from your answer got me to the right direction.